# Newbie question: no index.php? in my plain wordpress permalink

Tags: php, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

I am trying to learn about the Rewrite API and I see people write their plain permalink as "index.php?page_id=", but my local Wordpress site shows "?page_id=" instead. Is there any reason why it displays like that? Does it make any difference when rewriting permalinks?